# ValidationMessageFor not rendering error message

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a Partial View:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BM)
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BM)
```

In the main View, if I do:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.Partial("QuoteStep1", Model)
}
```

Then calling $('form').validate() validates the form and the error message is displayed if I don't fill in data.

However, if instead I load the partial view using an AJAX call, then calling   $('form').validate() still works (it returns true or false correctly) but the error message is no longer displayed !

I've read somewhere that I should add the following to the top of my Partial View:

```
@if (this.ViewContext.FormContext == null) 
{
   this.ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext(); 
 }
```

But it has no effects at all.

**[EDIT: UPDATE ON MY RESEARCH]**

After over 2 hours of debugging, I've found out a few things. First, because I load the content of the form using an AJAX request, the newly added HTML controls are not part of the DOM. Therefore, there's no way for the jquery validator to know about these controls.

So, adding the following line of code in the AJAX success callback SHOULD do the trick:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));
```

This is set right after the AJAX result is added to the DOM.

When I debug further into the validator, I can see that code being called:

```
 $(selector).find(":input[data-val=true]").each(function () {
            $jQval.unobtrusive.parseElement(this, true);
        });
```

Meaning, it found the newly added input box.

In the $jQval.unobtrusive.parseElement method the code below is hit:

```
 this.adapt({
                    element: element,
                    form: form,
                    message: message,
                    params: paramValues,
                    rules: rules,
                    messages: messages
                });
```

and the element is my textbox, the form is the View form and the message is "BM must be a number". So everything looks good to me.

But guess what... The validation error message still doesn't show up !

Any jquery guru out there to help please ? :)

Comment: great question. great research.

Comment: **Quote OP:**  _"calling `$('form').validate()` validates the form"_  ::  This is not true.  [`$('form').validate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) only _initializes_ the plugin on your form.

Comment: **Quote OP:** _"calling `$('form').validate()` still works (it returns true or false correctly) but the error message is no longer displayed"_ ::  [`$('form').valid()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) is the method you use to programmatically trigger a validation test (shows messages)

Comment: Maybe I was innacurate in my explanations, but the fact is that I still need to use validate() for my purpose, not the valid() function which does not perform the actual validation. I'm still stuck by the way :)

Comment: Before `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));` you must first call `$('form').data('validator', null);` to remove the existing validator

Answer (score -1):

I've also researched for this question a lot, and I find it to help me:
Just add 
$("#myForm").valid();
with:

```
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")' type='text/javascript'></script>
```